# Perform subtraction of the index in a *ngFor

Tags: angular

How can I make a calculation using the index? I want to apply the class danger when the condition is true, but I need to calculate i-1 within *ngFor loop.

```
<tr *ngFor="#org of data; #i = index">
    <td [ngClass]="{danger: org.price < data.stock[i-1].val }">
</tr>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code in your question?

Comment: Cannot read property val of undefined, in the following data.stock[i-1].val. If I use a static number it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not caused by `i-1` not working.
The index starts with `0`. Therefore I guess the issue is that `data.stock[-1]` is just invalid because accessing the index `-1` of an array is invalid.

Comment: You are right the issue was an invalid index of the array.

Comment: By the way, NG1 let me do this without an error (!)

Comment: I don'r know NG1 well. Maybe its index starts with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make any calculations you need in custom function, for example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<table>
               <tr *ngFor="let org of data; let i = index">
                 <td [ngClass]="{danger: org.price < org.stock[getIndex(i)].val }">
               ...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInits {
    ...
    // this is your custom function to set index as you need
    getIndex(index){
        var result = index - 1;
        if (result < 0 || result > 0) result = 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

See my quick example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/e1FhzsJUB1Lp9gALetAJ?p=preview)

*Note:*

- As @Günter pointed out: the negative index is invalid
- Is your `data` property an array of objects or just an object? It seems like it should be an array of objects where each object has an additional array property called `stock`.
- The `#`org within the `*ngFor` is deprecated and you should use [let](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html) instead.